# opening pseudo HTML .XLS on Google drive

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-sheets, xls

I downloaded a .xls file but cannot open it reasonably in Google Sheets.

I see some HTML-like code that includes the numbers but cannot be parsed using a simple HTML viewer.

Here is an [example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_sPnJmY7l8krUulS6EoBIvKqSfxbQLW-/view?usp=sharing).

Is there a way to open it using apps script? That would be the best. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to see the file of `https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_sPnJmY7l8krUulS6EoBIvKqSfxbQLW-/view?usp=sharing` at Google Spreadsheet.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Issue and solution:

When I saw your shared file, it was found that the file is a part of HTML data including the table. The file is not the Excel file. But the mimeType is `application/vnd.ms-excel`. By this, the file cannot be seen at the browser and converted to Google Spreadsheet.

In order to see the data of the table of the shared file with Google Spreadsheet, how about retrieving the table from the file and putting it to the Google Spreadsheet? By this, you can see it with Google Spreadsheet.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Apps Script, and [enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enabling_advanced_services). Then, run the function of `myFunction`.

```
function myFunction() {
  var fileId = "1_sPnJmY7l8krUulS6EoBIvKqSfxbQLW-";  // From the URL of https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_sPnJmY7l8krUulS6EoBIvKqSfxbQLW-/view?usp=sharing

  var html = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getBlob().getDataAsString();
  var table = html.match(/<table[\w\s\S]+?<\/table>/gi)[0];
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create("sampleSpreadsheet");
  var sheetId = ss.getSheets()[0].getSheetId();
  var resource = {requests: [{pasteData: {html: true, data: table, coordinate: {sheetId: sheetId, rowIndex: 0}}}]};
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(resource, ss.getId());
}
```

- When you run the script, new Google Spreadsheet is created to the root folder and put the table from the shared file to the Spreadsheet.

#### Note:

- For example, if you want to simply  confirm the HTML file as a PDF file, you can also use the following script.

  ```
  var fileId = "1_sPnJmY7l8krUulS6EoBIvKqSfxbQLW-";  // From the URL of https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_sPnJmY7l8krUulS6EoBIvKqSfxbQLW-/view?usp=sharing
  var blob = DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).getBlob().setContentType(MimeType.HTML).getAs(MimeType.PDF);
  DriveApp.createFile(blob.setName("sampleDocument"));
  ```

#### Reference:

- [Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.